# How to translate “my phone doesn’t have any signal”

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good way to translate *signal*, meaning the ability of your mobile phone to connect to the telephone network? Would something like this make sense in Esperanto?

> Mi ne ricevis vian telefonvokon ĉar mi vojaĝis en la kamparo kaj mia telefono ne havis *signalon*.

In French I think people use *réseau* which translates more cloesly to *reto*. Could that be a better way to say it in Esperanto?

Comment: As another data point: German uses "Empfang" (in the meaning of "reception", as in "radio broadcast reception") also for cell phone network availability. I don't know what the Esperanto equivalent of that would be, though.

Comment: Komputeko currently [translates "cellular signal"](https://komputeko.net/#cellular%20signal) as "ĉela signalo", but without giving any sources for that. I'm unsure how reliable that entry is.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I was asking this question in order to make [this game](https://gemelo.org/kongreso/). For the moment I have opted for “la telefono ne kaptas retkonekton”. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Mi pensas ke *signalo* estis sufiĉe bona vorto kaj ne necesis kompliki la aferon pli; sed estas kompreneble ke oni volas tovi la plej bonan esprimmanieron por la ludo.

Answer (score 3):

At least to me *signalo* is misleading, as if the phone could not play a ring tone or something like that. Like Joop, I would use wording that refers to net, connection or access.

For instance:

*Mia telefono…*

- *ne havis konekton al la reto / havis neniun konekton al la reto.*
- *ne havis aliron al la reto / havis neniun aliron al la reto.*
- *ne havis retaliron / havis neniun retaliron.*

Answer (score 1):

Mi preferas uzi vortojn 'senkomunikiĝi' aŭ 'elkomunikiĝi':

> Mi ne ricevis vian telefonvokon ĉar mia telefono elkomunikiĝis.

Aŭ por via ekzemplo:

> Mi ne ricevis vian telefonvokon ĉar mi vojaĝis en la kamparo kaj mia telefono estis senkomunikiĝa.

Comment: Kvankam mi mem estas komputila fantikulo kaj ĉi tial ofte parolas pri komputiloj kaj programoj kvazaŭ ili estus personaj, mi scias, ke multaj ne konsideras tion esti bona stilo. Ĉiokaze mi samopinias kun ili: "senkomunikiĝi" aŭ "elkomunikiĝi" faras telefonon tro persona, tro homa.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas, tio estas interesa, kiam mi konsultis [NPIV](https://vortaro.net/#senkomuniki%C4%9Da_kd) antaŭ ol respondi, mi ne rimarkis ke ĉi tiu vorto havas tian signifon. Sed kio estas pli persona ol telefono per kiu oni komunikas per iliaj?

Comment: Ne estas telefonoj, kiuj komunikiĝas inter si, sed homoj per telefonoj.

Answer (score 0):

Mia telefono ne havas reton.

Has no net is familiar in French and German for instance. And relates to signal.

Detektas/ricevas?